npm is not working and the version is also not showing in vs code
PS C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder (3)> npm --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
I try to install npm and show the version. Give me the solution
